# Displaying PDF file in a div or iFrame

Tags: php, pdf, html, iframe

Is there any way i can load PDF file (its contents) in a div or iFrame?

I have a bunch of PDF files on a server and, ideally, i need to have a button 'Show file' on a page, clicking on which will load the contents of selected file in a div(iFrame).

Comment: Using IFrames with PDFs would be inconsistant in each browser. Using divs might be the best bet for embedding a PDF into a web page and you could use PDFObject: http://pdfobject.com/instructions.php

Answer (score 7):

You can also use google pdf view by using `iframe` on your page :

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Instead of this in above code :

http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf

Use your own `PDF` file path.

You can view the `demo` here.

http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html

It's just a suggestion. No downvotes please.

Comment: Hmm.. i dont think that sending urls to google is a good idea. The contents is a private data.

Comment: @DeadMan This is good for non-private data. Definitely worth an up-vote ;)

Comment: @Fred Thanks your encouraging me.

Answer (score 0):

Google's gview is sometimes unresponsive and given 204 status. Here is the best free alternative.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66548544/2078462